# Как отправить email в unity webgl

Tags: unity3d, webgl

Нужно отправить email из приложения в webgl. Unity 5.5.0.
Открываю приложение через firefox,всё работает нормально, но когда нужно отправить email выскакивает ошибка

```
An error occurred running the Unity content on this page.
See your browser's JavaScript console for more info.
The error was:uncaught exception: Assertion failed: 0 && "The target
platform does not support Sockets", at:     
C:\ProgramFiles\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Generic\SocketImpl.cpp,48,SocketImpl 
at jsStackTrace (jaw 0.9.js:1:19540)
```

А вот что пишет в консоли браузера

```
Invoking error handler due to
uncaught exception: Assertion failed: 0 && "The target platform does not
support Sockets", at:
 C:\ProgramFiles\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp\libil2cpp\os\Generic\SocketImpl.cpp,48,SocketImpl
 at jsStackTrace (jaw 0.9.js:1:19540)
stackTrace (jaw 0.9.js:1:19711)
___assert_fail (jaw 0.9.js:1:222355)
```

Comment: webgl тут ни причем вобще

Comment: @ampawd причём вообще-то

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^^"

Answer (score 1):

Читаем [это](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html):

> No direct socket access
>
> Due to security implications, JavaScript code does not have direct
>   access to IP Sockets to implement network connectivity. As a result,
>   the .NET networking classes (ie, everything in the System.Net
>   namespace, particularly System.Net.Sockets) are non-functional in
>   WebGL. The same applies to Unity’s old UnityEngine.Network* classes,
>   which are not available when building for WebGL.

В WebGL доступны только Web Sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать параметр mailto:

```
Application.OpenURL("mailto:artron.classic@gmail.com");
```